# Indeterminate value of array

Tags: c++, arrays

may I ask someone to see whether my concept is right or not?

Suppose I define two arrays: `int integer[4];` and `char characters[4];`

1. If I didn't initialize the array elements and the array is defined within a function, the values of the array elements will be indeterminate (i.e. unknown / random).
2. If I didn't initialize the array elements and the array is defined in the global scope, the value of the `int` array elements will `0` and that of char array elements will be `'\0'`.

Is my concept correct?? Thanks!

Comment: Global variables and static variables are initialized to zero.

Comment: how about char array in global scope? default value of '0' or just '\0'

Comment: `char MyCharArray[1000]` will be initialized to 1000 0s if it's at the global scope.

Comment: @sehe: Not quite. There's a special concept of *zero-initialization* that's unrelated to value-initialization.

Comment: @KerrekSB :) Well. I could have known. RuleOfThumb: whenever you think there can't possibly be a different initialization method for this, in C++ assume there is

Comment: I guess that the OP's question is about initialization with 0 vs '\0' for a char array.

Comment: I have trouble seeing the difference @YvesDaoust `static_cast<char>(0)` is exactly `'\0'`

Comment: for 1. prefer the term indeterminate or unknown over random. Random might imply that it would be a good source for a random number generator which is certainly not the case.

Comment: thanks guys, very clear explanation!

Comment: @sehe: I know, you are asked an explanation by the OP.

Comment: repeating the question like that seemed like you were validating the question. It is, however, like asking why  heavier objects weigh more

Comment: @sehe: why would 0 and '\0' be the same ? One is an integer, the other a character.

Comment: Isn't 0 an integral literal. It's a valid initializer for any integral type. My $0.02

Comment: @sehe: this was worth being said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per §8.5/12

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized; if no initialization is performed, an
>   object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate value. [
>   Note:
>   Objects with static or
>   thread storage duration are zero-initialized, see
>    3.6.2
>   .
>   — end note
>   ]

Global variables and static variables both fall under the note, so they will be zero-initialized. Per §8.5/6,

> To
>   zero-initialize
>   an object or reference of type
>   T
>   means:
>   <...>
>
> - if
>     T
>     is a scalar type (
>     3.9
>     ), the object is initialized to the value obtained by converting the integer literal
>     0
>     (zero) to
>     T
>     ;
> - if
>     T
>     is an array type, each element is zero-initialized;

So, your assumptions are correct.